# Receiving error Too many SOQL queries: 101 even though I do not have any SOQL query inside FOR loop

Tags: trigger

My client has a trigger on User object in its org. Whenever a user is Activated/Deactivated, the trigger send out the notification email. Now whenever we want to do a bulk update on user records via dataloader we are receiving the error 
**false","false","CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY:UserTrigger: System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101**

We are unable to update more that 30 user records at a time. Below is the code for the same.

**Trigger**

```
trigger UserTrigger on User (after delete, after insert, after undelete, after update, before delete, before insert, before update) {

try{
    for(User usr : Trigger.new){
        User oldUser = Trigger.oldMap.get(usr.Id);
        User newUser = Trigger.newMap.get(usr.Id);
        if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate) {
            //UserTriggerHandler userTriggerHandler = new UserTriggerHandler();
            UserTriggerHandler.notifyifUserActivationChange(oldUser, newUser);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){ //This will fire upon creation of new User record.
        System.debug('An error has occurred:' + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

**Trigger Class**

```
global with sharing class UserTriggerHandler {

public static boolean runTestClass=false;//This variable is to skip the web service in test method.

public static void notifyifUserActivationChange(User oldUser, User newUser){
User myUser;
String Email, FirstName, LastName, Id, userType, mailSubject;
Boolean newState, oldState;

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    GetEmailsFromGroup emails = new GetEmailsFromGroup();

    List<String> mailToAddresses = emails.getEmailAddresses('SFDCADMINS');

    mail.setToAddresses(mailToAddresses );

if(runTestClass == false){        
  myUser = [select id, Name, Profile.Name, Profile.PermissionsModifyAllData from User where id = :Userinfo.getUserId()];
}

Try{  
  if (newUser.IsActive){
      newState = newUser.IsActive;
    }else{
      newState = false;
    }

  if (oldUser.IsActive){oldState = oldUser.IsActive;}

    Email = newUser.Email;
    FirstName = newUser.FirstName;
    LastName = newUser.LastName;
    Id = newUser.Id;
    userType = newUser.userType;
    if (newUser.IsActive){newState = newUser.IsActive;}

    System.debug('>>>: here1'+ oldState + ' ' + newState);        
  if (oldState != newState) {
    System.debug('>>>: here2');          
    if (newState) {mailSubject = 'activated';}//User has been activated.
    else{mailSubject = 'inactivated';} //User has been deactivated.

    mail.setSubject('SFDC - User ' + mailSubject);

    if(userType == 'Standard'){
      userType = 'Standard or BU Restricted';  
    }

    if(userType == 'CsnOnly'){
      userType = 'Chatter Free Only';
    }

      String  msg = 'The following User(s) have been ' + mailSubject + ' with a ' + userType + ' license:';
        msg = msg + '- ' + FirstName + ' ' + LastName + ' (http://login.salesforce.com/' + Id + ') - Changed by ' + myUser.Name + '\n'; 
        mail.setHtmlBody(msg);
    System.debug('>>>: here');  

    if(runTestClass == false){
      Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });    
    }
  }
}
catch(Exception e){ //This will fire upon creation of new User record.
  System.debug('An error has occurred:' + e.getMessage());
}

}
}
```

Please help me in identifying the issue .

Thanks!
Ruchi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you have a query inside your loop: `notifyifUserActivationChange` is called inside the `for` loop on the trigger, which does perform a query. Your function needs to be bulkified to support lists of users, which in turn can be queried in bulk.

Comment: If I try to update the **OldUser/NewUser** values as a list then will this solve my problem ? Sorry but I am unable to test this as I will have to try updating the user records which I do not want to do unless I am sure of it working fine.

Comment: : Also Can you please let me know what does GetEmailsFromGroup() do ? This trigger has been written by someone else and seems to be bit confusing to me.

Comment: Yes, you should update your users by calling the function with list parameters, and modifying the function to operate on a list of users. As to the other question, it is presumably a class used to extract email addresses from a public group whose users are defined as admins that should receive the message.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Will update the trigger accordingly and see if it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not bulkfied, and can lead to some governor limits.

You are calling `notifyifUserActivationChange()` within a loop, and in notifyifUserActivationChange() you might have several SELECT SOQL:

1. [select id, Name, Profile.Name, Profile.PermissionsModifyAllData from User where id = :Userinfo.getUserId()]
2. Not sure about the "content" of `GetEmailsFromGroup()`, but you probably have one or more SOQL statements there as well.

You are also sending email within a loop. 10 calls to SendMail and you reach governor limit.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out for the Email limits.  This trigger has been written by someone else previously which seems to have not been checked thoroughly which is creating problems now :( . I will check for the Email limits too as pointed out by you.